# How to display text data in react redux component after state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, pdf.js

I want to display text from pdf file in the component TextItem (in appview.jsx) and I thought the component would be re-rendered whenever its state changes. But the component doesn't display new text and from console I know that state is changed. What mistake did I allow? How to get the desired behavior of the program?

appview.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
var PDFJS = require('pdfjs-dist');
import { default as InputFile } from './components/inputfile.jsx';
import { default as FileList } from './components/filelist.jsx';
import { writeCurrentFile, showPDF } from "./actions.jsx";
import '../css/styles.scss';


PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
    '../build/webpack/pdf.worker.bundle.js';


class TextItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.text} //I have problem here.
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class AppView extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    uploadFileHandler = e => {
        const file = e.target.files[0]
        if(file !== this.props.currentFile) {
            this.props.writeCurrentFile(file);
            this.props.showPDF(file, this._pageContainer, this.props.pages);
            console.log("Text: ", this.props.text);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <div className="Sidebar">
                <div className="ButtonField">
                    <InputFile uploadFileHandler={this.uploadFileHandler.bind(this)}>
                        Select a PDF file
                    </InputFile>
                </div>
                <FileList currentFile={this.props.currentFile}/>
            </div>
            <div className="center">
                <div className="Content">
                    <h2 style={{ marginTop: 0, color: "#efefef" }}>
                        Your PDF file will be viewed here.
                    </h2>
                    <div ref={c => this._pageContainer = c}></div>
                </div>
                <div className="TextField">
                    <TextItem text={this.props.text} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>)
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        text: state.get("text"),
        pages: state.get("pages"),
        currentFile: state.get("currentFile")
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        writeCurrentFile: file => dispatch(writeCurrentFile(file)),
        showPDF: (file, _pageContainer, pages) => dispatch(showPDF(file, _pageContainer, pages))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppView);
```

actions.jsx

```
var PDFJS = require('pdfjs-dist');


export function writeCurrentFile(file) {
    return {
        type: "WRITE_CURRENT_FILE",
        file
    }
}

export function showPDF(file, _pageContainer, propsPages) {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    let pages = propsPages;
    let newPages = [];
    let textPages = [];

    console.log("First from showPDF!");

    fileReader.onload = e => {
        PDFJS.getDocument(new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).then(pdf => {

            let scale = 2.0;
            let viewport, canvas, context, renderContext;
            const pageContainer = _pageContainer;
            pages.map( page => pageContainer.removeChild(page) )

            for (let i = 1; i <= pdf.numPages; i++) {
                pdf.getPage(i).then(page => {

                    viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

                    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions.
                    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                    canvas.height = viewport.height;
                    canvas.width = viewport.width;

                    page.getTextContent().then(text => {
                        console.log("Begining getTextContent");
                        var txt = text.items.map(s => s.str).join(' ');
                        console.log("From getTextContent: ", txt);
                        textPages.push(txt);
                    });

                    // Render PDF page into canvas context.
                    renderContext = {
                        canvasContext: context,
                        viewport: viewport
                    };

                    page.render(renderContext);
                    pageContainer.appendChild(canvas)
                    newPages.push(canvas)
                }); 
            }
        });
    }

    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

    return {
        type: "SHOW_PDF",
        newPages,
        textPages
    }
}
```

reducer.jsx

```
import { Map } from "immutable";

var reducer = function(state = Map(), action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_STATE":
            return state.merge(action.state);
        case "WRITE_CURRENT_FILE":
            return state.set("currentFile", action.file);
        case "SHOW_PDF":
            state = state.set("pages", action.newPages);
            return state.set("text", action.textPages);

    }
    return state;
}

export default reducer;
```

app.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from "./reducer.jsx";
import AppView from "./appview.jsx";


const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

store.dispatch({
  type: "SET_STATE",
  state: {
    text: [],
    pages: [],
    currentFile: null
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppView />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Thank you guys for your answers :).

Comment: In your appview can you add this line to your render() to see if the text value is changed on rerenders? `console.log(this.props.text);` if text is changed then theres no reason why TextItem will not rerender because the props have changed.

Comment: I added console.log(this.props.text); and it returns changed state. But, unfortunately, TextItem don't rerender.